# pandas + python : merge 2 dataframes cell by cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cells

I have two `pandas.DataFrame` :

```
values = pandas.DataFrame([[0, 1], [7,5]], columns=["a", "b"], index=[1, 2])
info = pandas.DataFrame([["foo", "bar"], ["few", "tar"]], columns=["a", "b"], index=[1, 2])
```

`values` and `info` are settings for users so I want to print a chart by merging the dataframes cell by cell on all the columns to get something like this :

```
    a           b
1   0 : foo     1 : bar
2   7 : few     5 : tar
```

How can I do this without a for loop ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert `values` data type to str and add the two data frames with `:` as separator.

```
values.apply(lambda col: col.astype(str)) + " : " + info

#   a       b
#1  0 : foo 1 : bar
#2  7 : few 5 : tar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .merge method built into pandas.

So for your case it would be something like:

`pd.merge(values, info, how='inner', on='user)`

It works just like a join in SQL.

There are a bunch of example in this article:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: it returns an empty dataframe

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd    

values = values.astype(str)
info = info.astype(str)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = values['a'] + ':' + info['a']
df['b'] = values['b'] + ':' + info['b']

print(df)
```